# Dependent fields in Lucene

Tags: .net, lucene.net, lucene

Assume I have a list of objects that look like this:

```
class AuctionItem
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  byte[] Image {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to store them in a Lucene `Document` like so:

```
foreach(var auctionItem in AuctionItems)
{
  doc.Add(new Field("Name", ... ) );
  doc.Add(new Field("Image", ... ) );
}
```

When querying the index, I want to ensure that I get one or more documents back where the Name field is grouped together with the Image field since the Name is related to the Image.

[image]

Is there a way to do this with Lucene?

Comment: You want to group documents with the same name? Documents with same image? The question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Each Document contains multiple instances of AuctionItem. When a single Document is returned by some query, I need to have the Name field associated with the Image field. Now, if there are multiple Names and multiple Images, how do I know which Image goes with which Name?

Comment: You will not be able to do what you want if you add various auctionitens to the same document. When you add a field multiple times, lucene just appends them together: http://docjar.org/docs/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add(Fieldable). Why can't you put each auctioniten in a different lucene document?